# Display text dynamically in jsp

Tags: jsp

I'm designing a login form so when the user enters a wrong username or password i must display "wrong credentials". Can i do it dynamically in the same page ?
I tried passing a attribute using request to specify wrong credentials but in my jsp page, when i do this

```
    <%if (request.getAttribute("wrong").equals("yes")) {%>
        <p class="small">Wrong Credentials</p> <%} %>
```

i get nullpointer exception. What am i doing wrong and what is the best way to do it ?

Comment: Where was this attribute set?

Comment: In the servlet which handle login requests. If password  is false setAttribute is used to set this and then request is forwarded using getRequestDispatcher.forward .

Comment: request.setAttribute("wrong", "yes");   

request.getRequestDispatcher("/WebSites/Index/index.jsp").forward(request,response);

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my ignorance. A try catch around the if condition in jsp solved the problem.